# Query does not return expected result based on parameterized WHERE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

my procedure are not giving me the result that I want
is it because the comparison is between 2 varchar variables?

it should take the staff number and property rent price as parameters

this is the code I wrote

tables:
[image]
[image]

```
create or replace procedure proprety_info ( p_sno staff.sno%type, p_rent property_for_rent.rent%type)
as
cursor executive is
select  s.sno, fname, pnum, street, rent 
from staff s, property_for_rent p
where s.sno = p.sno
and  p_rent < rent;

begin

for v_loop in executive loop

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('staff number:  ' || v_loop.sno);
dbms_output.put_line ('staff name:  ' || v_loop.fname);
dbms_output.put_line ('property number:  ' || v_loop.pnum);
dbms_output.put_line ('street:  ' || v_loop.street);
dbms_output.put_line ('rent price:  ' || v_loop.rent);

    end loop;
END proprety_info;
/
set serveroutput on;
exec proprety_info('sg14',400);
```

the result I got:

```
staff number:  sa9
staff name:  mary
property number:  pa14
street:  16 high st
rent price:  650

staff number:  sg14
staff name:  david
property number:  pg16
street:  5 novar rd
rent price:  450

staff number:  sg37
staff name:  ann
property number:  pg21
street:  18 dale rd
rent price:  600
```

what I expected:

```
staff number:  sg14
staff name:  david
property number:  pg16
street:  5 novar rd
rent price:  450
```

Comment: Does the SELECT standalone produce the expected result?

Comment: provide the table structure

Comment: No, I need cursor because it will return more than one result

Comment: `p_sno` is not used in the code. Why should it have any influence?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should have:

```sql
cursor executive is
  select  s.sno, fname, pnum, street, rent
  from staff s, property_for_rent p
  where s.sno=p_sno and s.sno = p.sno
    and  p_rent < rent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH 
    staff AS
        (
            Select 'sa9'    "SNO", 'Mary'   "FNAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 'sg14'   "SNO", 'David'  "FNAME" From Dual Union All
            Select 'sg37'   "SNO", 'Ann'    "FNAME" From Dual 
        ),
    property_for_rent AS
        (
            Select 'pa14' "PNUM", '16, High St.' "STREET", 650 "RENT", 'sa9'  "SNO" From Dual Union All
            Select 'pg16' "PNUM", '5, Novar Rd.' "STREET", 450 "RENT", 'sg14' "SNO"From Dual Union All
            Select 'pg21' "PNUM", '18, Dale Rd.' "STREET", 600 "RENT", 'sg37' "SNO" From Dual 
        )
select  s.sno, fname, pnum, street, rent 
from staff s, property_for_rent p
where s.sno = p.sno
and  100 < rent           -- p_rent = 100 

SNO  FNAME PNUM STREET             RENT
---- ----- ---- ------------ ----------
sa9  Mary  pa14 16, High St.        650 
sg14 David pg16 5, Novar Rd.        450 
sg37 Ann   pg21 18, Dale Rd.        600 


select  s.sno, fname, pnum, street, rent 
from staff s, property_for_rent p
where s.sno = p.sno
and  100 < rent       -- p_rent = 100
and 'sg14' = s.sno    -- p_sno = 'sg14'

SNO  FNAME PNUM STREET             RENT
---- ----- ---- ------------ ----------
sg14 David pg16 5, Novar Rd.        450
```

Your Cursor (1st SQL) doesn't filter the SNO column by function parameter (p_sno) so you got 3 rows.
If you use that filter too  (2nd SQL) - you should get what you need...
Your Cursor definition should look like below...

```sql
Select  s.SNO, s.FNAME, p.PNUM, p.STREET, p.RENT 
From    STAFF s  
Inner Join  PROPERTY_FOR_RENT p ON(s.SNO = p.SNO)  -- use this sintax to join tables - it is a standard & good practice since '92. (or near)
Where   p_rent < p.RENT And p_sno = s.SNO
```